# Should we allow additional, brand-specific questions that have general but incomplete answers elsewhere?

Tags: discussion

For context, I'm thinking of these two:

- [What do all those parts in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-does-all-those-parts-in-a-lens-name-mean)
- [Nikon lens naming [closed]](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/nikon-lens-naming-closed)

While the second question is answered by the answer to the first, I think that there are a couple of failings of such broad answers:

- not all lenses are going to be included.  Pentax - a major manufacturer - is absent, and checking my shelf, other missing makes are: Zeiss (of several different eras/mounts), Cosina/Voigtländer, and Bronica.  Leica lenses would require an answer at least as long as the existing one.  It doesn't seem feasible t expand the answer to be all-inclusive.
- many aspects of particular mounts/lenses are ignored or glossed over, but which are likely to be important for buying/using those lenses. For example, mount incompatibilities.

A community wiki is one solution, but I think not the best one; there are concrete answers to these questions, and secondly because people are likely going to be after specific information. A Canon user is unlikely going to be interested in the details of Nikon's nomenclature.  I think we could get some very useful and very high-quality answers about specific brands, maybe we should let those evolve, at least for a while?

Answer (score 3):

I'm happy to let it evolve for a little while. I think the Nikon lens naming one is close enough to be closed, but I don't think we should close "[What is DT series of Sony lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/what-is-dt-series-of-sony-lenses)". I think that is a very specific question about one particular aspect, and answers could have a brief background about what sort of cameras DT lenses would work with and other pros and cons, which aren't so relevant for a broader question.

Answer (score 3):

Although I was one of the voters to close "Nikon lens naming", it now came to mind that very specific questions are actually better from SEO perspective than one all-inclusive list, because when people google "what is DT series of Sony lenses" they're more likely to find the specific question than the list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind specific questions per se, the reason I voted for closing of Nikon lens naming was that answer to that question was already contained in the generic one.

Comment: I think the catch for me is that it's only *partly* answered there; there are aspects to Nikon's mount that bear mentioning in a specific question that don't in a general one. E.g., G lens compatibility.  Similar things are true of most mounts.